# JSF ajax exception handler not working

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

Using BalusC answers on multiple questions about handling JSF ajax exceptions I tried:

- omnifaces.FullAjaxExceptionHandler
- custom handler

result is always same - response to any exception during ajax event is page looking like this:
[image]
and exception on regular `h:commandButton` redirects to login page. Wich is strange, because should redirect to 404.xhtml

anyway:
here is my web.xml:

```
<error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/errors/404.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/errors/404.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/errors/404.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
```

here is my customExceptionHandler:

```
@Override
    public void handle() throws FacesException {

        final Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> i = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator();

        while (i.hasNext()) {
            ExceptionQueuedEvent event = i.next();
            ExceptionQueuedEventContext context
                    = (ExceptionQueuedEventContext) event.getSource();

            // get the exception from context
            Throwable t = context.getException();

            final FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

            //here you do what ever you want with exception
            try {

                //log error ?
                logger.info("error thrown {}", t);

                //redirect error page
                fc.getExternalContext().redirect("http://www.o2.pl");
                fc.renderResponse();

                // remove the comment below if you want to report the error in a jsf error message
                //JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(t.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                //remove it from queue
                i.remove();
            }
        }
        //parent hanle
        getWrapped().handle();
    }
```

plus in my server (wildfly 9.0.0) log there is only this message logged from customExceptionHandler:
`(default task-104) error thrown {}: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/login.xhtml - View /login.xhtml could not be restored.
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:212)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:123)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)`

I switched once again to omnifaces.FullAjaxExceptionHandler, and this is server log:
`[org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler] (default task-27) FullAjaxExceptionHandler: An exception occurred during processing JSF ajax request. Error page '/errors/404.xhtml' will be shown.: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/login.xhtml - View /login.xhtml could not be restored.`

So problem is same.

Plus this is how the page looks like:
[image]

as far as I understand, both handlers are correctly fired, but somehow, their response is corrupted.
So the big question is - what am I doing wrong? what I missed?

**EDIT posting project description for BalusC**

here is my project structure:
[image]

and another part of my web.xml defining security:

```
 <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Secure assets</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>WRITER</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
```

**EDIT for BalusC reauest I post response headers**

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 22 Sep 2015 10:19:15 GMT
Expires:0
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Pragma:no-cache
Server:WildFly/9
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:Undertow/1
```

**EDIT source of error**

ajax that makes error is attached to a button:

```
<h:commandLink value="#{msg.add}">
   <f:ajax render=":addingModalBody"
           execute="@this"
           listener="#{myBean.setFields()}"
           onevent="renderAddModalBody"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Goal of this button is to set value on backing bean (listener) on that value render body of modal (render) and show modal (onevent).

Comment: Problem is answerable if problem actually **only** occurs during a `ViewExpiredException` because of a session expiration and there's an authentication framework which forces a redirect to login.xhtml when user is not logged in (also because of a session expiration). In all other cases, the error page is correctly shown, right? If so, you'd need to tell which authentication framework you're using, because the problem needs to be solved over there.

Comment: That was my first thought. That's why I moved all my error pages outside restricted part of project - wati - I'll post picture and description

Comment: right now I'm testing `ViewExpiredException` when user is logged in.

Comment: sorry - I messed up your edit on my question :/

Comment: @BalusC do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Press F12, check browser's HTTP traffic monitor (Network) and tell which response headers were being set when you saw that raw XML response.

Comment: I added headers to question

Comment: Content type looks good. But there are a some duplicate headers which is strange in first place. Anyway, was this the direct response to the ajax request, or was it redirected and did you then got this response? (i.e. double redirect and thus the last request was actually a synchronous request and not an ajax request)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90313/discussion-between-lucius-snow-and-balusc).